# Phalcon Multi module - Dynamic Module registration

Tags: php, frameworks, phalcon, phalcon-routing

Hi guys Im using the following structure for a multi-module project in Phalcon

```
[modules]

   [module1]
        [controllers]
        [models]            
        [views]
   [module2]
        [controllers]
        [models]            
        [views]
   [module-n]
        [controllers]
        [models]            
        [views]
```

I have registered only Module 1 and Module 2 in my bootstrap index.php file. Like this:

```
$this->registerModules(array

       (
        'Module1' => array(
            'className' => 'Modules\Module1\Module',
            'path' => '../modules/module1/Module.php'
        ),

        'Module2' => array(
            'className' => 'Modules\Module2\Module',
            'path' => '../modules/module2/Module.php'
        )
    ));
```

Now, my default module is Module 1 . How do i use Controllers of module n(this module has not been registered). Is there any dynamic way of registering modules?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you should avoid using one module controller in another module. This is not a correct way for application to behave ;) This is more about general good programming and design patterns, not the phalcon itself. You can for example use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture

There is possibility to register services dynamically and share them between modules, if you are looking for implementation in Phalcon, you can check Vegas CMF: http://vegas-cmf.github.io/1.0/guide/di/service-manager.html